# Running out of memory when expanding an symbolic expression using rules.How to handle such cases?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, simplifying-expressions, replacement

while deriving equations related to dynamics of 6 connected body, I ended up creating about 3000 set of rules,because of which final expression looks simple, now the issue is when i want to resubstitute using replace all option, i'm running out of memory.(When i checked in Task manager the memory column show 100% and got shutdown) How to handle such cases.
My code looks like this

```
rules1 = Dispatch[{a -> Sin[t], b -> (a*Cos[t])/(2 + a), 
 c -> b^2 + a*Sin[t] + 1, d -> c^2 + b*Cos[t] - c*b}];

 f[t] = a/E^b + c*Sin[d] //. rules1

 Plot[f[t], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

Comment: What do you get when you evaluate [`$HistoryLength`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$HistoryLength.html)? "Using smaller values of $HistoryLength can save substantial amounts of memory in a Wolfram System session." BTW your code example doesn't work. Definition for `f` should be `f[t_] = ...`

Comment: Do your rules have a circular reference anywhere? So `a` depends on `d` which depends on `a`? Also, you should be able to separate resolving the rules from the function, `resolved = a/E^b + c*Sin[d] //. rules1` and then `f[t_] := resolved`.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, thanks for the response. $HistoryLength seems to have no impact on my problem.

Comment: @MikeY , I check it properly ,I don't have any circular references in my set of rules.I'm struck at the "resolved"  part of expression. Thanks for the response.

Comment: What happens when you run `/.` instead of `//.`?  Manually toggle through applying the rules? How many times until it burps, and what is left?